# How to replace sun.util.caldender.ZoneInfo with new API in java

Tags: java, api, junit, timezone, internals

I found this Api Sun.util.calendar.zoneInfo inside one of my Testcase and when I compile it I got the waring message it saying sun.util.calender.ZoneInfo is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

```
@Test @Ignore("This test case was previously ignore, appears incomplete")
    public void test_getTimeZoneFromTimeZoneDifferential() throws Exception {
        TimeZone customCali = DMessageFactory.getTimeZoneFromTimeZoneDifferential("110");
        System.out.println("\ncustomCali: "+customCali+"\n");
        String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
        for(int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(ids[i]);

            if(tz instanceof sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo) {
                TimeZone realZone = ((sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo) tz).getLastRuleInstance();
                if(realZone == null) {
                    if(tz.useDaylightTime() == customCali.useDaylightTime() &&
                       tz.getOffset(0) == customCali.getOffset(0)) {
                        System.out.println("match2: "+tz+"   "+tz.getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT));
                    }
                    //System.out.println("no real zone: "+tz);
                    continue;
                }

                if(customCali.hasSameRules(realZone)) {
                    System.out.println("match: "+realZone.getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT));
                }
                else if(realZone.getOffset(0) == customCali.getOffset(0)) {
                    //System.out.println("semi-match: "+tz);
                }
                else {
                    //System.out.println("NO-match: "+tz);
                }
            } else {
                //System.out.println("no-match: "+tz);
            }
        }
```

I really need to replace this  sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo and add another API without breaking its function, please help me out with this.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Use the modern *java.time* classes instead.

- [`java.time.ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) replaces `TimeZone`
- [`java.time.zone.ZoneRules`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html) replaces `sun.util.calender.ZoneInfo`

Loop all known zones, ask for the set of rules for that zone, specify a moment, and interrogate for the info you need.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
for( ZoneId z : ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds() )
{
    String zoneName = z.getDisplayName( TextStyle.SHORT , Locale.US ) ;

    ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;

    ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset​( instant ) ;
    int secondsOfOffset = offset.getTotalSeconds() ;

    boolean currentlyInDST = rules.isDaylightSavings( instant ) ;
    Duration amountOfCurrentDstAdjustment = rules.getDaylightSavings( instant ) ;

    …
}
```

## `sun.util.calender.ZoneInfo` is implementation backing `TimeZone` (both obsolete)

According to [this class JavaDoc](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/util/calendar/ZoneInfo.html), this is simply the concrete implementation backing the [`TimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html) class for JVMs provided by Sun.

> ZoneInfo is an implementation subclass of TimeZone that represents GMT offsets and daylight saving time transitions of a time zone.

Both `TimeZone` and `ZoneInfo` are obsolete. You should be using the modern *java.time* classes instead.

When building the [*Java Platform Module System*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System), Oracle began phasing out access to parts of their Java implementation that have become obsolete or were never intended for public consumption. This is an ongoing process. Any of your code calling on classes from the various `com.sun.*` packages should be rewritten to use other classes.

## java.time

[`TimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html) is one of the terrible date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. These are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern industry-leading *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### `ZoneId` = a time zone

A time zone is now represented with the [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) class, replacing `TimeZone`. The history of past, present, and future changes to the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) used by each region in a zone is tracked by the [`ZoneRules`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html) class.

### *tzdata*

Be aware that time zones are frequently changed by politicians around the world. This happens more frequently than you might think. These changes are tracked by the  the [*tzdata* data file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). Whenever changes occur in a zone you care about, you should update this time zone definition list in your installations of Java, your operating system, databases such as Postgres, and other libraries that manage their own time zone list.

### Zone rules

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Get the rules of that zone.

```
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;
```

### Zone rules for an `Instant`

An `Instant` represents a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), that is, a moment with an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours-minutes-seconds. By specifying a moment, you can ask questions of the rules in effect at that time.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
boolean currentlyInDST = rules.isDaylightSavings( instant ) ;
Duration amountOfCurrentDstAdjustment = rules.getDaylightSavings( instant ) ;
```

### Looping zones

You can re-implement your code by getting all time zones known by the embedded *tzdata* by calling the [`ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#getAvailableZoneIds()) method. You can loop the returned `Set`.

```
Set< String > zones = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds() ;
for( String z : zones )
{
    ZoneRules rules = ZoneId.of( z ).getRules() ;
    …
}
```

You do not explain your code such as what this means:

```
DMessageFactory.getTimeZoneFromTimeZoneDifferential("110")
```

…so there is not much more I can do for you.

Your code seems to be looking for a time zone that matches its [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (hours-minutes-seconds) and whether in [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) or not. As discussed above, you can interrogate the `ZoneRules` for this info.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).